# Composite unique index

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, composite-key

I have an object store which contains 3 indices, which are `name`,`value` and `userid`. How can I create a composite unique index from `name` and `userid`?

This is what I tend to do:

```
var objectStore = database.createObjectStore('data',{keyPath : ['name','userid']});
objectStore.createIndex('name','name');
objectStore.createIndex('value','value');
objectStore.createIndex('userid','userid');
```

Is `keyPath` good enough? Do I need to add another unique index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index that you set using the `createObjectStore` method is unique by default.

```
var objectStore = database.createObjectStore('data', { keyPath: ['name','userid']});
```

If you want to add more than one unique index to the store you can use the following code:

```
objectStore.createIndex('namevalue', ['name','value'], {unique: true});
```

Your store has 4 indices, the compound index counts as separate.

Comment: How did you know this? From this [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore#Parameters), the optional parameter doesn't have the `unique` option.

Comment: From the w3c the oficial documentation of the standard http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index

Comment: It's about the [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex) method. My task is here http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#h-options-object-concept

Comment: Correct, in the createObjectStore constructor, the second parameter is index and the only property you can modify is the auto increment. Additionally the since this will be the default DB index you don't need to set the property of unique. I'll update the code now.